# How to start an Android source code example on eclipse?

Tags: android

I have downloaded the samples from the SDK manager. Now, I want to know how to start it in eclipse.

When starting a new project, I select Android Project from Existing Code. Where can I get the path to that code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, New>Project...>Android>Android Sample Project then choose the platform(s) that you have installed and then the sample project you want to build and test.

Answer (score 0):

They are in your Android SDK folder.  On my machine the full path is

C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-17\AccelerometerPlay